# List not Expand when use Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to use Expandable Listview in Fragment.

I get Group name but when click on that unable to open child elements.

```
public class SavedTabsFragment extends Fragment {


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.saved_tab, null);
    ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    elv.setClickable(true);
    SavedTabsListAdapter  adapter= new SavedTabsListAdapter(getActivity());
    /*adapter.setInflater( inflater,
            getActivity());*/
    elv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return v;
}
 }
```

**SavedTabsListAdapter**

```
public class SavedTabsListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names",
        "Fish Names" };
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private String[][] children = { { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
        { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" }, { "Fluffy", "Snuggles" },
        { "Goldy", "Bubbles" } };

public SavedTabsListAdapter(Context ct) {
    ctx = ct;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.length;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return children[i].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return groups[i];
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return children[i][i1];
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
    CheckedTextView tv = (CheckedTextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(getGroup(i).toString());
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view,
        ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(getChild(i, i1).toString());
    return view;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out with the below Adapter code. Its working now.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SavedTabsListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private String[] groups = { "People Names", "Dog Names", "Cat Names",
            "Fish Names" };
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private String[][] children = { { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
            { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" }, { "Fluffy", "Snuggles" },
            { "Goldy", "Bubbles" } };

    public SavedTabsListAdapter(Context ct) {
        ctx = ct;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return children[i].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return groups[i];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return children[i][i1];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow, null);
        CheckedTextView tv = (CheckedTextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(getGroup(i).toString());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view,
            ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(getChild(i, i1).toString());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Just Change your line `public class SavedTabsFragment extends Fragment {` with `public class SavedTabsFragment extends FragmentActivity {` and constructor of your adapter class as `SavedTabsListAdapter  adapter= new SavedTabsListAdapter(SavedTabsFragment.this.getActivity());`

Comment: If I used FragmentActivity I got error in replace()  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menu_frame, new SavedTabsFragment()).commit();

Comment: Just clean your project.

Comment: Clean twice : The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, SavedTabsFragment)

Comment: Change it to `Fragment` it will have to be fragment as you might be loading it as fragment only. And tell me do you get error in constructor of your adapter ?

Comment: I used code which I post in Question. Now problem is List is not Expan

Comment: which one? Where you put adpter?

Comment: In my answer i have just shown the adapter code. That you have to use instead of your adapter class.

Comment: can we get method when click on group item ?

Comment: I used setOnGroupClickListener and get toast now I want to expand when click on this

Comment: Thanks I checked in device working. in emulator not working. Thanks